# How do I show my data as in interval form in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| ID | Class | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12th | 0 |
| 2 | 10th | 25 |
| 3 | 09th | 24 |
| 4 | 12th | 50 |
| 5 | 10th | 60 |
| 6 | 09th | 70 |

The desired output is like this:

| Marks | CLass12th | class9th | class10th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-25 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 25-50 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 50-60 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 60-70 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| **Total** | 3 | 2 | 3 |

How can I do the same with SQL?

Comment: Tag which DBMS(SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc ... ) are you using

Comment: Is the column class12th, 9th is static or vary if any new row with 8th is coming?

Comment: Classes are static

Comment: DBMS is SQL SERVER @Valerica

Comment: how are the marks build up ? why is 24 not included and why 50-60 ?

Comment: it is just a raw data @GuidoG

Comment: Still, we need to know the logic how to build your desired output from your sample data, raw or not

Comment: 0-25 means begin from 0 and end with 25 while 25 - 50 means begin after 25 and end on 50@GuidoG

Comment: @ShailendraPal well that's not very clear to anyone, is it? Don't overlap your categories - no-one will be sure of the true meaning and how to interpret the data. Do 0-24, 25-49 etc, or 0-25, 26-50 etc. Make up your mind and define it precisely. Otherwise, there's no way to know into which category a value of "25" will be placed - I assume you didn't intend for it to go into both. Ambiguity is a very bad thing in both programming and data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE marks 
  ( 
     id    INT, 
     class VARCHAR(200), 
     marks INT 
  ); 

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES     (1, 
            '12th', 
            0); 

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES     (1, 
            '10th', 
            25); 

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES     (1, 
            '9th', 
            24); 

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES     (1, 
            '12th', 
            50); 

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES     (1, 
            '10th', 
            60); 

INSERT INTO marks 
VALUES     (1, 
            '9th', 
            70);
```

-----not able to put (0-24) condition in marks as it is actually minus the value as -24  -----

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN marks >= 0 
              AND marks < 25 THEN ( 024 ) 
         WHEN marks >= 25 
              AND marks <= 50 THEN ( 2550 ) 
         WHEN marks >= 51 
              AND marks < 60 THEN ( 5160 ) 
         WHEN marks >= 60 
              AND marks < 71 THEN ( 6070 ) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END            AS marks, 
       Sum(class12th) AS CLass12th, 
       Sum(class10th) AS CLass9th, 
       Sum(class9th)  AS CLass9th 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               marks, 
               [12th] AS CLass12th, 
               [10th] AS CLass10th, 
               [9th]  AS CLass9th 
        FROM   (SELECT id, 
                       class, 
                       marks 
                FROM   marks) AS SourceTable 
               PIVOT ( Count(class) 
                     FOR class IN ([12th], 
                                   [10th], 
                                   [9th]) ) AS pivottable)a 
GROUP  BY marks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select '0-25', sum(case when class = '12th' then 1 else 0 end) '12th',sum(case when class = '10th' then 1 else 0 end) '10th',sum(case when class = '9th' then 1 else 0 end) '9th'
from Yourtable where marks >= 0 and marks < = 25
union
select '25-50', sum(case when class = '12th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '10th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '9th' then 1 else 0 end)
from Yourtable where marks >= 25 and marks < = 50
union
select '50-60', sum(case when class = '12th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '10th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '9th' then 1 else 0 end)
from Yourtable where marks >= 50 and marks < = 60
union
select '60-70', sum(case when class = '12th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '10th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '9th' then 1 else 0 end)
from Yourtable where marks >= 60 and marks < = 70
union
select 'total', sum(case when class = '12th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '10th' then 1 else 0 end),sum(case when class = '9th' then 1 else 0 end)
from Yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your ranges our use a CTE and use it in a query like this:

```
;with ranges as (
    select 0 fromMark, 25 toMark, '0-25' title
    union all select 25,50, '25-50'
    union all select 50,60, '50-60'
    union all select 60,70, '60-70'
    union all select 0,100, 'Total'
)
select 
    r.title,
    count(case when t.Class = '12th' then 1 end) Class12th,
    count(case when t.Class = '09th' then 1 end) Class9th,
    count(case when t.Class = '10th' then 1 end) Class10th
from yourTable t
left join ranges r
  on t.Marks >= r.fromMark and t.Marks < r.toMark
group by 
    r.title;
```